# form to mail not getting to exchange server recipient

Tags: exchange-server, sendmail, phpmailer

this is terrible for me now. i used php mail function and also use Contact Form 7 plugins too on my wordpress theme. also smtp plugins too. change many smtp server. but not work. mail function and Contact Form 7 both working fine on other mail account (gmail, yahoo. hotmail or any other pop mail) not just my client pop account. because they use microsoft exchange server.

for test issue i did something like i sent mail to frist to one gmail account and i setup in gmail auto fwd to one them that pop account . it working well but this problem is in mail show where it is from (xxxx@gmail.com) .. i don't want to show that gmail address. or i want direct send to that pop account.

server is godaddy

guys any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Google doesn't allow you to send from other addresses unless you are hosting your domain with them.